# Software Design - Interaction between two classes

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, client-server, client-side

First off, I am sorry if there is a trivial answer to this question but I am unable to find one.

The concept that I have in question is the following.
I have a client app and a server app that exchange data. I am trying to separate the logic that handles a server update in the client in the following way.

A "main" class that handles application logic and works with parsed and sanitized data and a "worker" class that parses the received data and calls the appropriate method of the "main" class. I guess this is in some way imitating events. Here is an example structure to make things more clear.

```
var Main = function(){
    this.init();
};

Main.prototype = {

    init: function(){
        //Do init logic

    },

    connect: function(){
        var client = new Client();
        client.onStateUpdate(this.executeStateUpdate);
        client.connect('localhost', 3001);
    },

    executeStateUpdate: function(data){
        // Problem - the "this" operator is now Client and not Main
    }

};


var Client = function(){
};

Client.prototype = {
    connect: function(host, port){
        this.client = new WebSocket("ws://"+host+":"+port);

        this.client.onmessage = function(e){
            var data = JSON.parse(e);
            //handle received data
            stateUpdate(data);
        };
    },

    stateUpdate: function(data){
        //sanitize data to application objects
        this.stateUpdateCallback(sanitizedData);
    },

    onStateUpdate: function(callback){
        this.stateUpdateCallback = callback;
    }
}
```

The biggest problem here is that calling "main" methods from the "worker" makes them point to the wrong object(e.g "Client" and not "Main").
I have thought about passing the "Main" class object to the "Client" object instead of callbacks, but this way I have to hardcode all the callback methods that would be called on each event that arises from the server. I am open to any suggestions on how to solve this matter and sticking to this architecture of the code is not mandatory for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this fully addresses your concern but solves one of your issues. `this` in javascript will always refer to the caller object. So if you want to call a Main method from the Client function and still want that `this` to reference Main inside Main's methods, you can use a helper function that will call any function using the `function.apply()` method.

Instead of:

```
    connect: function(){
        var client = new Client();
        client.onStateUpdate(this.executeStateUpdate);
        client.connect('localhost', 3001);
    },
```

use:

```
    connect: function(){
        var client = new Client();
        client.onStateUpdate(caller(this.executeStateUpdate));
        client.connect('localhost', 3001);
    },
    caller: function (fn) {
        var mainObj = this;
        return (function () {
            return fn.apply(mainObj);
        });
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Indeed this does resolve my issue with this way of handling things, but my other concern is whether this is actually a good architecture to use for the given problem.